# Error: could not find implicit value for parameter timeout: akka.util.Timeout

Tags: scala, akka-http

I have this code, where I am making an ask request in Scala:

```
 implicit val result =system.actorOf(Props(new TestActor("TestingName")),name = "Scala")

   val future3:Future[String]= ask(result ,Message).mapTo[String]
  val results = Await.result(future3, 5 second)
```

here my import statements

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.util.Timeout
import akka.pattern.ask
import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._
```

and I get the error messages like

**Error:(42, 35) could not find implicit value for parameter timeout: akka.util.Timeout**
   val future3:Future[String]= ask(result ,Message).mapTo[String]

**Error:(42, 35) not enough arguments for method ask: (implicit timeout: akka.util.Timeout)scala.concurrent.Future[Any].
Unspecified value parameter timeout.**
   val future3:Future[String]= ask(result ,Message).mapTo[String]

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the signature for `ask`, or `?`, you see:

```
def ask(message: Any)(implicit timeout: Timeout, 
                      sender: ActorRef = Actor.noSender): Future[Any]
```

It takes an implicit `timeout: Timeout` parameter which tells the future when to time out. You have to have it in scope when you call `ask`:

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import akka.util.Timeout

implicit val timeout: Timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
val future3: Future[String]= ask(result, Message).mapTo[String]
```

Comment: if instead of ask method if i go for ? symbol its working

Comment: Do you have an implicit timeout in scope? Because it doesn't seem so from your question.

Comment: implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
actually i have tried the ? its working perfectly when i try to use ask instead of ? i'm facing some problem anyways thanks for ur answer @Yuavl

Comment: And if you use `ask` with that timeout in scope you still get an error?

Comment: Yuval i think u r expert in scala  i'm new to scala  can u please tell me ur mail or fb id becaz i think u might help me alot

Comment: In DefaultJsonProtocol package we just used Json like jsonFormat5,jsonFormat2 jsonFormat1 what are all difference between 2,5,1 and why do we go for tat number?

Comment: That is a different question, I suggest you ask it in a new one

Comment: The is another question, I suggest writing it in a new one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148375/discussion-between-arvind-audacious-and-yuval-itzchakov).